# How to join three tables with outer join and cartesian product

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have three tables in a PostgreSQL DB: Users, Activities, Venues.

```
Users:
- id
- name

Visits:
- id
- user_id
- location_id

Venues:
- id
- name
```

I want to retrieve all activities for a specific user, event if the user haven't visited a location yet. I've tried it with some joins:

```
SELECT venues.id as venue, COUNT(activities.id) as visits
FROM users
RIGHT OUTER JOIN activities ON users.id=activities.user_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN venues ON activities.venue_id=venues.id
WHERE users.id=1234
GROUP BY venues.id
ORDER BY venues.id
```

I want the visits variable to contain 0 when the user haven't visited a location (= there is no entry in activities) and the count of activities if the user have visited the location.

But I only get the locations that the user have visited:

```
venue | visits
  1       3
  2       4
  3       22
  4       1
```

I thought, that the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` would return all entries from the right side, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A LEFT OUTER JOIN means that you want all of the entities from the left-hand table whether or not the JOIN condition (or predicate) is satisfied.

But this is also one of those rare cases where a Cartesian product (CROSS JOIN) is actually necessary since you want to see every venue for every user. Try using the [CROSS JOIN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_joins.htm) like this:

```
SELECT v.id as venue, COUNT(a.id) as visits
FROM users AS u
CROSS JOIN venues as v --<-- CROSS JOIN for Cartesian product between users and venues
LEFT JOIN activities AS a ON u.id = a.user_id AND a.venue_id = v.id
WHERE u.id = 1234
GROUP BY v.id
ORDER BY v.id
```

Comment: I've tried it, but I get the same output as the right join returns

Comment: thx for your edit, but I get an error, near the line `JOIN venues AS v`. Shouldn't it be `FROM users AS u, venues AS v` instead of the `JOIN venues as v`?

Comment: hmmmm, the `*=` does not work with PostgreSQL, is there another way? And why are you saying old school notation? ;)

Comment: Updated the cartesian product query. You need to explicitly specify `CROSS JOIN` to get the product.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj57522.html

Basic join explanations-- they can be confusing.  I think you either want to switch the columns in the first join, or use left outer join instead.

Comment: "they can be confusing" -- indeed, the author of the docs you linked to makes a misstatement: "A LEFT OUTER JOIN B is equivalent to B RIGHT OUTER JOIN A, with the columns in a different order" -- surely they meant, "...with the **tables** in a different order".